# Grid Search the number of hidden layers with keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, hyperparameters

I am trying to optimize the hyperparameters of my NN using Keras and sklearn.
I am wrapping up with KerasClassifier (it´s a classification problem).
I am trying to optimize the number of hidden layers.
I can´t figure it out how to do it with keras (actually I am wondering how to set up the function create_model in order to maximize the number of hidden layers)
Could anyone please help me?

My code (just the important part):

```
## Import `Sequential` from `keras.models`
from keras.models import Sequential

# Import `Dense` from `keras.layers`
from keras.layers import Dense

def create_model(optimizer='adam', activation = 'sigmoid'):
  # Initialize the constructor
  model = Sequential()
  # Add an input layer
  model.add(Dense(5, activation=activation, input_shape=(5,)))
  # Add one hidden layer
  model.add(Dense(8, activation=activation))
  # Add an output layer 
  model.add(Dense(1, activation=activation))
  #compile model
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=
  ['accuracy'])
  return model
my_classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)# Create 
hyperparameter space
epochs = [5, 10]
batches = [5, 10, 100]
optimizers = ['rmsprop', 'adam']
activation1 = ['relu','sigmoid']
# Create grid search
grid = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=my_classifier, 
param_distributions=hyperparameters) #inserir param_distributions

# Fit grid search
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Create hyperparameter options
hyperparameters = dict(optimizer=optimizers, epochs=epochs, 
batch_size=batches, activation=activation1)
# View hyperparameters of best neural network
grid_result.best_params_
```

Comment: Keras models are static in that matter. You must create many models yourself and see which one performs better.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to make the number of hidden layers a hyperparameter you have to add it as parameter to your `KerasClassifier` `build_fn` like:

```
def create_model(optimizer='adam', activation = 'sigmoid', hidden_layers=1):
  # Initialize the constructor
  model = Sequential()
  # Add an input layer
  model.add(Dense(5, activation=activation, input_shape=(5,)))

  for i in range(hidden_layers):
      # Add one hidden layer
      model.add(Dense(8, activation=activation))

  # Add an output layer 
  model.add(Dense(1, activation=activation))
  #compile model
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=
  ['accuracy'])
  return model
```

Then you will be able to optimize the number of hidden layers by adding it to the dictionary, which is passed to `RandomizedSearchCV`'s `param_distributions`.

One more thing, you probably should separate the `activation` you use for the output layer from the other layers.
Different classes of activation functions are suitable for hidden layers and for output layers used in binary classification.