# Tuning number of hidden layers in Keras

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, mnist

I'm just trying to explore keras and tensorflow with the famous MNIST dataset.
I already applied some basic neural networks, but when it comes to tuning some hyperparameters, especially the number of layers, thanks to the sklearn wrapper `GridSearchCV`, I get the error below:

`Parameter values for parameter (hidden_layers) need to be a sequence(but not a string) or np.ndarray.`

So you can have a better view I post the main parts of my code.

**Data preparation**

```
# Extract label
X_train=train.drop(labels = ["label"],axis = 1,inplace=False)
Y_train=train['label']
del train

# Reshape to fit MLP
X_train = X_train.values.reshape(X_train.shape[0],784).astype('float32')
X_train = X_train / 255

# Label format
from keras.utils import np_utils
Y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes = 10)
num_classes = Y_train.shape[1]
```

**Keras part**

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Function with hyperparameters to optimize
def create_model(optimizer='adam', activation = 'sigmoid', hidden_layers=2):
  # Initialize the constructor
    model = Sequential()
      # Add an input layer
    model.add(Dense(32, activation=activation, input_shape=784))

    for i in range(hidden_layers):
        # Add one hidden layer
        model.add(Dense(16, activation=activation))

      # Add an output layer 
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
      #compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=
     ['accuracy'])
    return model

# Model which will be the input for the GridSearchCV function
modelCV = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)
```

**GridSearchCV**

```
from keras.activations import relu, sigmoid
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.utils import np_utils

activations = [sigmoid, relu]
param_grid = dict(hidden_layers=3,activation=activations, batch_size = [256], epochs=[30])
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=modelCV, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy')
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

I just want to let you know that the same kind of question has already been asked here [Grid Search the number of hidden layers with keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47788799/grid-search-the-number-of-hidden-layers-with-keras) but the answer is not complete at all and I can't add a comment to reply to the answerer.

Thank you!

Comment: I managed to get a different error message, meaning I could have solved the issue linked to hidden_layers by iterate on enumerate(hidden_layers). Now, I just get "'int' object is not iterable", which is less interpretable than the previous error.

Answer (score 3):

You should add:

```py
for i in range(int(hidden_layers)):
    # Add one hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(16, activation=activation))
```

Try to add the values of **param_grid** as lists :

```py
params_grid={"hidden_layers": [3]}
```

Comment: Thanks but I got the same error message. I'm not sure it comes from the loop, cause when I run it alone, everything is fine. Might it come from the GridSearchCV function?

Comment: could you **print** the content of **params_grid** ?

Comment: Sure here you have :``` {'hidden_layers': 3,
 'activation': [<function keras.activations.sigmoid(x)>,
  <function keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.0, max_value=None, threshold=0.0)>],
 'batch_size': [256],
 'epochs': [30]}```

Comment: @Mez13 please do not use the comments space to post such stuff - edit & update your question accordingly

Comment: Ok. Where am I supposed to answer a question asked in the comments then? Thanks. And what about my initial problem by the way?

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting your parameter hidden layer =2 it goes as a string thus an error it throw.

Ideally it should a sequence to run the code that's what you error says

Comment: Do you mean the parameter by default? Because in my GridSearch I set it at 3. Anyway, why does it interpret 2 as a string? And how can I overcome it?